# How to set ylim and xlim in plot raster in R

Tags: r, plot, raster, shapefile

I'm making a raster data ploting in R, when I adjust to the area I'm working on, R displays the ylim that doesn't want to be cut off.

I tried:

```
# set lon lat
ylim=c(-4,2)
xlim=c(118,126)

plot(pm10_mean,xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
plot(shp, add=TRUE)
plot(shp2, add=TRUE)
```

but I got picture like this

[image]

How to remove free space above 2 and below -4? I just want to plot area in `xlim` and `ylim`

Comment: Try setting `yaxs="i"` and `xaxs="i"`. That  is something like `plot(pm10_mean,xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")`.

Comment: still same, nothing happens

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. May be you want to have a look at the `raster` package to `clip` the image first.

Comment: I tried to clip but it doesnt help to remove the space

Comment: You just need to resize the window

Answer (score 3):

I think `spplot` works fine but I find it really slow and hard to customize.

I found a more recent [duplicate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379591/how-can-i-constrain-my-plot-to-the-extent-of-the-raster-image/380999#380999) of this question in gis.stackexchange and provided the below answer:

I found that `raster::plot`'s documentation indicates that you can specify the plotting window and in my experience it has zero effect.  Instead it will always assume the extent of the raster you give it.

My suggested workaround is to first draw your desired plot window with a blank object then *add* the raster plot to this window.

```
my_window <- extent(-4, 2, 118, 126)
plot(my_window, col=NA)
plot(my_raster, add=T)
```

For me, this achieves what I'm after.  The caveat is if you're plotting a stack or brick, the add functionality doesn't work in my experience.  The solution is to use `subset`, like `plot(subset(my_brick,4), add=T)`

Comment: " you can specify the plotting window and in my experience it has zero effect."  is an odd statement as any simple test shows that it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before. You can manually resize the plot area to remove the blank areas, or insert polygons to cover the unwanted areas of shapefile. But the safest option is to use `spplot` as this will automatically resize the plotting area for you:

```
require(maptoolS)
require(raster)

data(wrld_simpl)
rs=raster()
rs[]=1
id_shp=wrld_simpl[which(wrld_simpl$ISO2=="ID"),]
rs=crop(rs,id_shp)
rs=disaggregate(rs,40)
rs=mask(rs,id_shp)

spplot(rs,ylim=c(-4,2),xlim=c(118,126),sp.layout=list('sp.lines', id_shp, lwd=2,first=F))
```

[image]

Comment: I want not only land to have a raster value but also the sea

Comment: That was just demonstration as you did not provide a reproducible example. Take the last line of my code and change "rs" to "pm10_mean" and "id_shp" to "shp" to match your data

Answer (score 0):

Just as easy to simply plot a NULL plot and add your raster

```
plot(NULL, xlim = c(-114.5, -35.5), ylim = c(-24.5, 29.5), asp = 30/30,
     xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude")
plot(your_raster, add = T)
```

Stacking still seems to work